# Bootstrap working perfectly on localhost but not working on VPS

Tags: php, jquery, linux, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my bootstrap/php code working perfectly on xampp localhost but when I upload it to my /var/www folder with apache and mysql installed on the server, suddenly half of my coded bootstrap does not show up. What should I do? Do I need to install something on my VPS like xampp? VPS has Linux Ubuntu  Debian-7.0 (64 bit).

Thank you!

Comment: What errors do you have in the console?

Comment: um how can I check that? I'm new to VPS so help me if you can

Comment: In the browser`s console you should get some errors